# В чем отличия архитектуры EPIC от VLIW?

Tags: архитектура

И конкретно есть вопрос про конвейеризацию в данных архитектурах. Слышал, что в EPIC "защищенный конвейер" (он остановится, если мы попытаемся использовать результат выполнения инструкции до того, как она готова) и он использует DPL (Deep Pipeline-Latency).

Во VLIW же "незащищенный конвейер" и в нем нет interlocks. Но, к сожалению, нигде информации в интернете не могу найти. И правильна ли эта информация? Может есть подробный источник (или Вы)? Спасибо!

**UPD:** еще слышал, что во VLIW архитектурах есть подклассы: запись результата выполнения инструкции строго через определенное количество циклов или же ранее "максимальной задержки" - может это еще как-то вносит различие в архитектуры...